# Cyclic Redundancy check : Single and double bit error

Tags: crc, crc32, crc16, error-correction, crc64

Found this in the book by Forouzan (Data Communications and Networking 5E). But, not able to understand the logic behind this.

This is in the context of topic **two isolated single-bit errors**

> In other words, g(x) must not divide x^t + 1, where t is between 0 and n − 1. However, t = 0 is meaningless and t = 1 is needed as we will see later. This means t should be between 2 and n – 1

why t=1 is excluded here? (x^1 + 1) is two consecutive errors, it must also be detected right using our g(x).

[image: 2 isolated 1 bit error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something similar was brought up and answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312309/cyclic-redundancy-check-single-and-double-bit-error) .

Comment: @rcgldr sir, my doubt is in the paragraph quoted above the author said-- for detecting 2-bit isolated error (x^i + x^j) => x^j[x^(i-j) + 1] , let (i-j) = t --> our polynomial generator should not divide (x^t + 1) where, t is from 2 to n-1. t=0 is meaningless (I understand) but why excluding t=1? 2 consecutive error must also be detected right?

Comment: If you could update your question to include the later part of the book where it explains why "t = 1 is needed", that would help. Seems it would be better stated that g(x) must not divide (x^i + x^j), where i ≠ j, and i+j < n.

Comment: @rcgldr yes, I have referred Tanenbaum and there also they are not saying something about the lower bound of t. I don't know why they have excluded t=1 in forouzan book.  I have added the screenshots you can check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third image states that (x+1) should be a factor of g(x), but this reduces the maximum length that the CRC is guaranteed to detect 2 bit errors from n-1 to (n/2)-1, but it provides the advantage of being able to detect any odd number of bit errors such as (x^k + x^j + x^i) where k+j+i <= (n/2)-1.

Not mentioned in the book, is that some generators can detect more than 3 errors, but sacrifice the maximum length of a message in order to do this.

If a CRC can detect *e* errors, then it can also correct floor(*e*/2) errors, but I'm not aware of an efficient algorithm to do this, other than a huge table lookup (if there is enough space). For example there is a 32 bit CRC (in hex: 1f1922815 = 787·557·465·3·3) that can detect 7 bit errors or correct 3 bit errors for a message size up to 1024 bits, but fast correction requires a 1.4 giga-byte lookup table.

As for the "t = 1 is needed", the book later clarifies this by noting that g(x) = (x+1) cannot detect adjacent bit errors. In the other statement, the book does not special case t = 0 or t = 1, it states, "If a generator cannot divide (x^t + 1), t between 0 and n-1, then all isolated double bit errors can be detected", except that if t = 0, (x^0 + 1) = (1 + 1) = 0, which would be a zero bit error case.

Comment: Thank You, sir, I can't agree with you more :)

Comment: Hello, I am a beginner in CRC. Things are not that intuitive to me. So sorry, if I am asking anything too trivial or silly.. Please can you explain `this reduces the maximum length that the CRC is guaranteed to detect 2 bit errors from n-1 to (n/2)-1`, the mathematics I mean, a little bit?

Comment: For odd bit errors, we need `(x+1)` to be a factor of `G(X)`, i.e. `G(X)=(x+1).F(X)`. `F(x)!=1`.


And for two bit errors, `G(X)` should not divide `(x^t+1)` and hence `(x+1)`, for `t==1`.


Now if `G(x)` has `(X+1)` as factor, then also `G(X)` shall not divide `(x+1)`. Because based on our assumption, `(X+1)/G(x)=1/F(X)` and this does not have remainder `0`... So why not have t==1 condition as well... This is my thought process...

Comment: Or it is so that based on this: `Now if G(x) has (X+1) as factor, then also G(X) shall not divide (x+1). Because based on our assumption, (X+1)/G(x)=1/F(X) and this does not have remainder 0... So why not have t==1 condition as well...` 


`t==1` need not be satisfied explicitly? (I mean implicitly is it being satisfied?) so they are removing `t=1` condition ... [as other options make sure that G(x) does not divide (x+1) as I thought in the above comment]

Please can you help me... @rcgldr

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh - I updated my answer. The "t = 1 is needed" is clarified later by stating g(x) = x+1 cannot detect adjacent errors, and then in another statement, doesn't special case t = 0 or t=1, just stating "t between 0 and n-1", except the t = 0 case is zero errors, since (x^0 + 1) = (1 + 1) = 0.

Comment: Ok, @rcgldr, I think I have got the point now. The problem I guess arose because of the language of the text... The text special case `t=1` and "it is needed" is used in the sense that `t=1 is indeed needed to be considered as a possible value of t so that our g(x) works fine`

Comment: If my last comment is correct, @rcgldr please can you explain me, why in the summary [Third picture third point] the authors are considering, `t=2 to n-1` along with the other three points? It is so because that the so called good `g(x)` as per points 1,2,4 mentioned, cannot divide `(x^1+1)` so they are not including it? [Not considering t=0 is fine as it is non sense]

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh - I consider to be a mistake or at least confusing. It would be simpler to state `t = 1 to n-1`.  (As noted above, t = 0 is a zero bit error case).